# How to add a Javascript library to Angular 4 component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to figure out how to import JavaScript files **ONLY** to a specific component.

I put the following code directly into my component:

```
import "../../vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js";
import "../../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js";
import "../../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js";
```

But it fires an error saying:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in...

Which makes me suspect that the files that depend on jQuery cannot find the jQuery library in this scope.

jQuery itself is put in the `angular-cli.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
    "./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
],
```

An alternative is to put all of those 3 external JS files into the angular-cli.json file as well, and it will work, showing the expected result from the user perspective.

But I would like to figure out how to avoid setting the JS globally for those that are used only in a few specific components.

Thanks, please advise.

Comment: have you installed files using npm?

Comment: Hi brk, for the jquery, I would like to use an external file which I downloaded myself instead from the npm install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, to import jQuery to your component, you should write:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Which means *"Import all and use as "$" from "jQuery""*.

If you downloaded the library by yourself, without `npm install`, you can try the following (but I'm not sure that it will work):

```
import * as $ from 'path/to/jquery';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, though I need to set the AllowJs to true in tsconfig.json

Comment: @Zan, nice to hear, that it help you. Cheers